# How to boot windows command prompt from USB

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I want to boot cmd.exe from a USB or boot disk. How would I go about doing this? I would prefer not to used something like MS-DOS as it is extremely outdated. I'm running 7, if it matters.

Comment: Nowadays people may use a WinPE e.g. BartPE, then open a command prompt from there. So booting Windows off boot media, could be off USB, then open a command prompt.  But also you can boot into windows recovery and open a command prompt by hitting F8 twice - once to get the normal F8 menu and again for extra options. There is also UBCD and UBCD4WIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmd.exe is a Windows application and cannot be used as a stand alone shell. A good alternative is [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/). There is also a [USB bootable version](http://chtaube.eu/computers/freedos/bootable-usb/). A better alternative is any [Linux distribution](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop).

If you really want cmd.exe then you can [reboot in safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode#1TC=windows-7) and choose the command prompt option. This only works when you have a full Win 7 installation on the machine though. Otherwise, you can [do the same from an Win 7 install disk](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/682-command-prompt-startup.html). These options will both actually be running cmd.exe on top of the Windows kernel though.